# Stripe - unable to make a transfer to connected standalone account

Tags: stripe-payments, stripe-connect

We are using Stripe payment gateway in one of the application.

In our model we will have customers and stripe connected accounts.
We will charge customers for certain services and then periodically(weekly/monthly etc) transfer share of customer revenues to
connected accounts. Connected account holders are sort of business partners.
I am being able to successfully create customers with card and charge them later using Stripe java API. But I am having problems with transferring amount to standalone connected accounts.
I am connecting to standalone accounts by following [this](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/standalone-accounts) link in Stripe documentation.
After connecting to a standalone account i am receiving account's stripe account id, publishable key, token etc in the response that i am storing in database.
Later on while trying to transfer funds to this connected account i am getting an exception.

```
com.stripe.exception.InvalidRequestException: No such token: pk_test_kXinGPY8H2cyc5vWOQagwkbE;
```

I am really not sure what should be the value of 'source' parameter when making transfer to connected account. Should it refer to payment earlier charged to the customer? Since there will be more than one payments charged to customers and only one periodic transfer to connected account I am not sure what should be the source.

My sample code is as,

```
Stripe.apiKey = "platform account's secret key"
Charge charge = null;
Map<String, Object> chargeParams = new HashMap<String, Object>();
chargeParams.put("amount", 200);
chargeParams.put("currency", "usd");
chargeParams.put("source", "pk_test_kXinGPY8H2cyc5vWOQagwkbE"); //{platform accounts public key}
chargeParams.put("destination", ""acct_18gKXJHZfNFseiFv""); //Connected account's id        
charge = Charge.create(chargeParams);
```

I just wanted to know if the business scenario described above can be achieved through Stripe gateway. And if yes, someone please point me to any mistakes that i am possibly doing in above sample code.
Thanks.

**EDIT:**

So it seems, under normal circumstances, Stripe does not allow transfer of funds from one Stripe account to other without transfer being 
directly linked to a customer charge. 
It allows special case transfers from one Stripe account to other but mandates that volume of such payments can not exceed 10% of your overall
transactions.

I our case we just need to pay our sub-merchants their share of revenue periodically and it doesn't necessarily has to be a stripe-to-stripe transfer. we can always register our client as one of the customer in his/her own Stripe platform account. We will add client's credit/debit card details to this customer
account. We can then use client's customer account to transfer funds to standalone accounts.

It should work, right?

Answer (score 2):

A typical payment flow with Stripe can be divided in two steps:

1. Client-side, in your frontend code (HTML + JavaScript), you use [Checkout](https://stripe.com/docs/checkout) or [Stripe.js](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe.js) (configured with your publishable API key) to collect the customer's payment information and turn it into a token. Once the token has been created, you then send it to your server.
2. Server-side, in your backend code (in your case, in Java), you use the token to actually [create a charge](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge).

The issue in your code is that you're using your publishable key as the [`source`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-source) parameter. This parameter should contain the ID of the token created in the frontend. Token IDs are strings that start with `"tok_"` followed by random alphanumeric characters.

The rest of your code looks correct, although you might want to add an [`application_fee`](https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge-application_fee) parameter if your platform needs to take a cut out of the transaction. As it is, your platform would pay Stripe's fees, but receive no money out of the transaction since all the funds are sent to the connected account.

Comment: thanks for reply. In my case we will be capturing customer card details on front-end only once. using Stripe.js we are retrieving card token and creating a customer in the application using that card token. Subsequently we will charge the stored customer as and when need arises using the stored card. And then transfer part of payment charged to customer to connected account. And this is where i am having issues; in making transfer to connected account.

Comment: @ivish: If you already have a customer object, you simply need to _not_ pass a `source` parameter in your charge creation request, and instead pass a `customer` parameter with the customer ID.

Comment: We are successfully being able to charge a customer using stored card. That is not the problem. Our problem is we are not being able to make a transfer to connected account. In our scenario we will charge a customer multiple times over a month. At the end of month we need to transfer part of the payments received from customers to connected account.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not a compliant use of Stripe. The funds must be split between the platform and the connected account when you create the charge, using the `application_fee` parameter. You cannot create charges on the platform, then later transfer the funds from the platform to the connected account.

Comment: Yes, that is really unfortunate since we have already invested lot of development effort assuming that to be the case. But we can still use special case tranfer - https://stripe.com/docs/connect/special-case-transfers - by adhering to certain rules and limits, right?

Comment: Yes. The most important limit is that special-case transfers should not make up more than 10% of your overall volume, so it's definitely not possible to use them to transfer ~most of your volume to connected accounts. In any case, I recommend you reach out to Stripe's support to explain your business model and ask for more information: https://support.stripe.com/email.

Comment: Thank you Ywain. Yes, i have already written to Stripe support.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you create a special customer linked to the Company's target bank account and charge "him" to transfer to your share holders ? Unless you use stripe for some auditing you can just use it as a channel.